# How to comment a grammar rule in yacc and a regex matching rule in lex?

Tags: flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I want to comment this matching rule in lex. I don't want to delete it. I just want it commented so anyone sees the lex file later be informed that this part has been commented

```
<tickPragma_name_1>. {
    myyyless(0);
    BEGIN (0);
}
```

how I can do that? I know that I can comment the C code inside the {} .but I want to comment the whole rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can surround the rule with `/*` and `*/`, just as in C, but with two major caveats:

1. Everything needs to be indented by at least one space, including the `/*` (and, I believe, the contents).
2. There cannot be any nested comments in the action.